# Flet Page Navigation

Tags: python, flet

I have an app I'm making but the top navigation wont reroute to the Account Page
this is the App bar Controls

```
# App Bar Controls
class Appbar(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, page) -> None:
        self.page = page
        super().__init__()

    def account_page(self, event):
        self.page.go('/account')

    def test_01(self):
        print('Ola Comsta')

    
    def topnav(self):
        return AppBar(
            center_title=Text('Main Page'),
            leading=IconButton(icons.MENU_ROUNDED, on_click=self.test_01),
            title = navbar.UserData('Thabang Teddy', 'Big Data Software Developer'),
            actions=[
                PopupMenuButton(
                    items=[
                        PopupMenuItem(text='Account', on_click=self.account_page),
                        PopupMenuItem(text='Settings'),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
            bgcolor='blue800'
        )
```

The main function that has the rerouting functionalities and all the pages is this one:

```
def main(page: Page) -> None:
    page.title = "Index-I"
    page.window_width = 400       # window's width is 200 px
    page.window_height = 800       # window's height is 200 px
    page.window_resizable = False 

    # page.horizontal_alignment='center'
    # page.vertical_alignment='center'
    page.scroll = ScrollMode.AUTO
    appbar = Appbar(page)

    

    def route_change(e: RouteChangeEvent) -> None:
        page.views.clear()

        page.views.append(
            View(
                route='/',
                controls=[
                Text(value='Index-I', size=50, color='white'),
                IconButton(
                    icon=icons.NAVIGATE_NEXT,
                    icon_color="blue400",
                    icon_size=40,
                    tooltip="Open",
                    on_click=lambda _: page.go('/mainpage'))],
                vertical_alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                spacing=26,
            ),
            
            
        )

       
        # MainPage View
        if page.route == "/mainpage":
            topnav = appbar.topnav()
            page.views.append(
            View(
                route='/mainpage',
                controls=[
                    topnav,
                    FloatingActionButton(
                                icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS_ROUNDED,
                                on_click=lambda _: page.go('/')
                            ),
                    Text(
                        value = 'Analytics',
                        weight = 'BOLD',
                        size=25,
                        text_align = 'CENTER'                                   
                    ),
                    Row([
                        Text(
                            value = 'BALANCE',
                            size=10),
                        Text(
                            value = '$40 000.00',
                            weight= 'BOLD'),
                    ])
        ]
            )
            )


          # Account View
        if page.route == "/account":
            topnav = appbar.topnav()
            page.views.append(
            View(
                route='/account',
                controls=[
                    topnav,
                    FloatingActionButton(
                                icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS_ROUNDED,
                                on_click=lambda _: page.go('/')
                            ),
                    Text(
                        value = 'Profile',
                        weight = 'BOLD',
                        size=25,
                        text_align = 'CENTER'                                   
                    ),
                ]
            )
            )


        page.update()

    def view_pop(e: ViewPopEvent) -> None:
        page.views.pop()
        top_view: View = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)
```

I want to basically change the pages or atleast reroute to the desired pages but i keep getting an error about:
`self.page.go('/account') ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Attribute Error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'go'`
I don't know what to do anymore.